# Setting SASS vars according to class

Tags: css, function, if-statement, sass

I need to set vars according to a class which are **.withtable** and **.notable** and the positioning of elements is different. [See the image](http://prntscr.com/duazbk) or check the code example:

```
body.withtable {
 $logo_width: 130px;
 $logo_height: 80px;
}
body.notable {
 $logo_width: 200px;
 $logo_height: 100px;
}
```

How to solve this thing? Any ideas?

Comment: That's how CSS variables (custom properties) work.

Comment: they are not css vars, but sass.

Comment: I know that. What I am saying is, CSS variables will work the way you want SASS variables to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass the variables that way. You might want to approach this the following way however:

```
.logo {
    body.withtable & {
        $logo_width: 130px;
        $logo_height: 80px;
        width: $logo_width;
        height: $logo_height;
    }
    body.notable & {
        $logo_width: 200px;
        $logo_height: 100px;
        width: $logo_width;
        height: $logo_height;
    }
}
```

This keeps the code readable and manageable as you keep your logo properties in one place. Placing the `&` character at the end checks if this is a parent instead of a child of `.logo`.

This compiles into:

```
body.withtable .logo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 80px; }

body.notable .logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px; }
}
```